# DevTools failed to load SourceMap

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create pages that will take a user information and save them to the database. the user information are {name, age....... picture}, when I put the information without a picture it work fine and the data saved to the database but when I try to put the picture with them it gives me the error.

[image: erreur]

I'm sorry for the picture quality. 
any one can help me with this. 
I'm using nodejs and react
thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to send the picture as Base64 in your object, as it follows:

```
var data = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 27,
  picture: 'data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhPQBEAJos...',
}
```

In NodeJS, if using Express, the picture will be `req.body.picture`. So, all you need to do is store the file, then get the temp path do do what you need.

You can store base64 file doing:

```
var filePath = './tmp/myPicture.png';

fs.writeFile(filePath, req.body.picture, 'base64', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    res.json({ err: 'Error while creating temp file from base64.' });
  } else {
     // Your file was uploaded, so you can read your file here.
  }
});
```